# How to display data from another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys

I know this question might be silly, but I'm totally new to ASP.NET and spent whole day trying to solve this out unsuccesfully. Here is my problem:

I have two models

1.

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class Student
    {       
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string DeptID { get; set; }

    public Dept dept { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

2.

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
   public class Dept
   {
    [Key]
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to make a view with all Student data and Dept Name. How can I do it?

Comment: Its really unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please update with any details and code of what you *have already* tried.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using entity framework linq queries and have a dbContext with above two entities.

Now you can get all students data with departments on your controller like this:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students = dbContextObject.Students.Include(x=>x.dept);
```

It will bring all students records with their department in dept property of Student class. Now you can return this students list to your view and on your view you will receive it in your view model like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>
```

now use @foreach on your view inside a tr like this to generate td for student name and dept:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <td>@item.Name</td>
   <td>@item.dept.Name</td>
}
```

It will display all students name with their dept name on your view. Hope this helps you.